# Why am I getting a \omit error?

Tags: graphics, floats

Apologies if any of the formatting is wrong in this- first time using stack exchange.

I am attempting to use a mix of tabular/multicolumn to make a 3 part figure: one plot that spans the entire width of the document, and two plots beneath it that span half the width.

However, I am getting  "misplaced \omit" error and I'm not sure why. I've searched around the existing ones, but none of their errors seem to apply in my case.

The relevant code is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4wide]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c}
\centering
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{Figure1.pdf}}\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\footnotesize(a)} \\
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{Figure2.pdf} &\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{Figure3.pdf}\\
{\footnotesize(b)} & {\footnotesize(c)}
\end{tabular}
\caption{\textbf{I'd really love if this worked}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I've tried removing/adding the "\" between lines to no avail as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Ah apologies for missing the extra bits in code- my bad!

Comment: `\centering` after `\begin{tabular}` makes no sense. Try to remove it.

Comment: Woops- stupid on my part- thanks! However, now I get an error that my \hbox is too wide, and adding the multicolumns in the first place was supposed to avoid that. Does it matter that the images are PDFs? Or eps files as well/ tried that too just for fun. (And png)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: user41916: Putting two images of width `.5\textwidth` each next to each other in a tabular will get too wide because the table adds space. Try the column declaration `{@{}c@{}c@{}}`.

Answer (score 2):

The `demo` option is only to show the result without having your pictures.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
%\centering
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{Figure1.pdf}}\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\footnotesize(a)} \\
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{Figure2.pdf} &\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{Figure3.pdf}\\
{\footnotesize(b)} & {\footnotesize(c)}
\end{tabular}
\caption{\textbf{I'd really love if this worked}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `subfigure`s?

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe} % provides images in this example

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image-a}
    \caption{Image A}
  \end{subfigure}
  \vskip10pt % add vertical space 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.48\textwidth} % make less than .5\textwidth to avoid overfull \hbox 
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image-b}
    \caption{Image B}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.48\textwidth} % make less than .5\textwidth to avoid overfull \hbox 
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image-c}
    \caption{Image C}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{This works!}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]